# Should I put an air purifier in my computer room?

Tags: physical-environment

My small computer room (~250 sq ft) seems dusty.

Is there any reason against putting an air purifier in a computer room? Could it cause problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run servers in a room by themselves with the door locked and an A/C vent blowing cold air inside.  No matter how often I cleaned the A/C filter, the servers still got dust on them.

I did go and buy a $150 air cleaner (one with the ION) and it did collect a lot of dust.
Had to clean it once a week
My servers still collected dust though.

1. Clean the filters often (once a month) buy the cheap ones and keep replacing
2. Make sure your room is clean from floor to ceiling (ceiling tiles can collect dust)
3. Maybe put a filter on the vent that blows air into the room
4. Check with an A/C repair company, maybe you have a lot of dust in the vents and ducts.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend adding filters (or cleaning the existing filters) to your air cooling system, as well as sealing the room more effectively so that dust can't get in in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

what's the reason for putting one in?   Filtration needs to occur pre entry into the cooling system -otherwise cooling degrades.  putting one anywhere else in the system just means (maybe) slightly less dirty air gets to the chiller.  Dust on your PC can be removed with a can of "air" dust on the chiller needs an expensive hvac tech (to use a can of "air"...)